# cabal fails to build plutus-core

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

When [installing plutus starter](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter) on a Mac M1 running macOS 12.1 Monterey, the command `cabal build` logs the following error, even after updating cabal:

```
Failed to build plutus-core-0.1.0.0.
Build log (
/Users/dlindberg/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.7/plts-cr-0.1.0.0-63317e8e.log ):
Configuring library for plutus-core-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing library for plutus-core-0.1.0.0..
Building library for plutus-core-0.1.0.0..
[  1 of 197] Compiling Crypto           ( plutus-core/src/Crypto.hs, dist/build/Crypto.o, dist/build/Crypto.dyn_o )
[  2 of 197] Compiling Data.Aeson.Flatten ( plutus-core/src/Data/Aeson/Flatten.hs, dist/build/Data/Aeson/Flatten.o, dist/build/Data/Aeson/Flatten.dyn_o )
[  3 of 197] Compiling Data.Aeson.THReader ( plutus-core/src/Data/Aeson/THReader.hs, dist/build/Data/Aeson/THReader.o, dist/build/Data/Aeson/THReader.dyn_o )
[  4 of 197] Compiling Data.ByteString.Hash ( plutus-core/src/Data/ByteString/Hash.hs, dist/build/Data/ByteString/Hash.o, dist/build/Data/ByteString/Hash.dyn_o )
[  5 of 197] Compiling Data.SatInt      ( plutus-core/src/Data/SatInt.hs, dist/build/Data/SatInt.o, dist/build/Data/SatInt.dyn_o )
[  6 of 197] Compiling ErrorCode        ( common/ErrorCode.hs, dist/build/ErrorCode.o, dist/build/ErrorCode.dyn_o )
[  7 of 197] Compiling PlutusCore.Constant.Dynamic.Emit ( plutus-core/src/PlutusCore/Constant/Dynamic/Emit.hs, dist/build/PlutusCore/Constant/Dynamic/Emit.o, dist/build/PlutusCore/Constant/Dynamic/Emit.dyn_o )
[  8 of 197] Compiling PlutusCore.Data  ( plutus-core/src/PlutusCore/Data.hs, dist/build/PlutusCore/Data.o, dist/build/PlutusCore/Data.dyn_o )
[  9 of 197] Compiling PlutusCore.DataFilePaths ( plutus-core/src/PlutusCore/DataFilePaths.hs, dist/build/PlutusCore/DataFilePaths.o, dist/build/PlutusCore/DataFilePaths.dyn_o )
[ 10 of 197] Compiling PlutusCore.Pretty.ConfigName ( plutus-core/src/PlutusCore/Pretty/ConfigName.hs, dist/build/PlutusCore/Pretty/ConfigName.o, dist/build/PlutusCore/Pretty/ConfigName.dyn_o )
[ 11 of 197] Compiling PlutusPrelude    ( prelude/PlutusPrelude.hs, dist/build/PlutusPrelude.o, dist/build/PlutusPrelude.dyn_o )
[ 12 of 197] Compiling PlutusCore.Pretty.Utils ( plutus-core/src/PlutusCore/Pretty/Utils.hs, dist/build/PlutusCore/Pretty/Utils.o, dist/build/PlutusCore/Pretty/Utils.dyn_o )
[ 13 of 197] Compiling PlutusCore.Pretty.Readable ( plutus-core/src/PlutusCore/Pretty/Readable.hs, dist/build/PlutusCore/Pretty/Readable.o, dist/build/PlutusCore/Pretty/Readable.dyn_o )
<command line>: dlopen(/Users/dlindberg/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/lib/libHScrdn-crypt-clss-2.0.0-65075d2b-ghc8.10.7.dylib, 0x0005): symbol not found in flat namespace '_crypto_generichash_blake2b'

Failed to build small-steps-test-0.1.0.0.
Build log (
/Users/dlindberg/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.7/smll-stps-tst-0.1.0.0-5d2f50de.log ):
Configuring library for small-steps-test-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing library for small-steps-test-0.1.0.0..
Building library for small-steps-test-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 5] Compiling Control.State.Transition.Trace ( src/Control/State/Transition/Trace.hs, dist/build/Control/State/Transition/Trace.o, dist/build/Control/State/Transition/Trace.dyn_o )
<command line>: dlopen(/Users/dlindberg/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/lib/libHScrdn-crypt-clss-2.0.0-65075d2b-ghc8.10.7.dylib, 0x0005): symbol not found in flat namespace '_crypto_generichash_blake2b'
cabal: Failed to build plutus-core-0.1.0.0 (which is required by
test:plutus-example-projects-test from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0 and
exe:plutus-starter-pab from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0). See the build log above
for details.
Failed to build small-steps-test-0.1.0.0 (which is required by
exe:plutus-starter-pab from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0 and
test:plutus-example-projects-test from plutus-starter-0.1.0.0). See the build
log above for details.
```

Comment: are you using nix?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue solved** by following the detailed instructions for Mac M1 installation at  https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).